# How do I specify a generic in Type.GetType()?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am working on a VS extension that will generate documentation comments for a file. Roslyn provides classes that allow processing of source code and adding the comments. The specific problem I am having is determining the fully qualified name for a base class or interface in a class declaration. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

public class MyClass: IEnumerable
{ ... }
```

for which I want to generate:

```
<summary></summary>
<seealso cref="System.Collections.IEnumerable"/>
```

I determine that IEnumerable is defined in System.Collections by looping through each of the using directives to pick up the IdentifierName or QualifiedName and appending the interface name to generate a potential fully qualified name. I then call Type.GetType(potentialFullyQualifiedName), which returns the type if the name is valid, and null otherwise. If the returned value is not null, then I know I have the valid fully qualified name. For the example above, I first try
"System.IEnumerable" which returns null. Then "System.Collections.IEnumerable" which returns a type, so I know I have the correct fully qualified name. Everything is good so far.

But if I change the code being processed to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MyClass : IEnumerable<int>
{ ... }
```

everything I have tried returns null. IEnumerable is in System.Collections.Generic, so I will limit further discussion to that.

None of:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<out T>
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable`1
```

return a type from Type.GetType(). How do I specify the interface name to get Type.GetType() to return a type rather than null?

After looking at the first comment and first answer below, neither of which provide a "solution", it appears I need to add a bit more information.

The source code that I included above is just that, source code, or in other words, text, that is parsed to create a syntactic model which I then go through. I can't instantiate a Class1 object because the source code has not been compiled and is not part of the assembly that is processing the syntactic model. I could compile the source code to produce a semantic model of the source code, but that is potentially an expensive operation that I would much rather avoid. So it comes down to how do I determine that IEnumerable is actually System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, given that I only have IEnumerable as text?

Comment: You need System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Comment: @Evk, thanks for the suggestion, but that does not work either.

Comment: How exactly? I verified and it returns type, not null.

Comment: @Evk Well I tried it and it returned null, but I just tried it again and it does return the type. I don't know why it didn't work the first time. Thanks for forcing me to try it again.

Comment: Probably you just used wrong ` symbol (it should be backtick and not ' for example). As you probably understand already, 1 is number of generic parameters. For types like Tuple it will be 2 (or more).

Comment: @Evk I thought I tried both, but point is now moot. Thanks for the information about the number being the number of generic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the format of the full name for generic classes is a little bit different. It additionally includes the generic type's **namespace** and **full assembly identifying string** enclosed into [].

I wrote a short example to illustrate it. Consider we have the following 2 types:

```
class NonGeneric : IEnumerable
```

and

```
class Generic : IEnumerable<string>
```

...and the following code which prints interface names into console:

```
var nonGeneric = new NonGeneric();
var generic = new Generic();
string nonGenericName = nonGeneric.GetType().GetInterfaces().First().FullName;
string genericName = generic.GetType().GetInterfaces().First().FullName;

Console.WriteLine($"Non generic: {nonGenericName}");
Console.WriteLine($"Generic: {genericName}");
```

The output:

```
Non generic: System.Collections.IEnumerable
Generic: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: your answer gives a bit of an explanation possibly as to why my attempts do not work. I cannot apply this because your code starts with instantiating an object of the child class. I added a couple of paragraphs to my original post that explains why I cannot instantiate such an object. Basically, I have a syntatic model of the code, not a compiled version, and therefore the code is not part of the assembly that does the analysis.
I did try feeding something similar to your program's output into GetType(), but that did not work either.

Comment: Hm, I see in the comments that it actually worked for you in the end. But what if someone (unintentionally of course) defines a custom interface which is coincidentally also named IEnumerable but is located in a different namespace? Does your VS extension perform its lookup only through imported usings?

Comment: If a person defines an IEnumerable in the same namespace as MyClass, then that is the one that is selected. I will include a check to determine that.

If the interface is defined in a different namespace, then an ambiguous reference error is noted by the compiler. The programmer should resolve that before generating the documentation. There is no way I can or want to force a person to generate the documentation at a specific time.